# Set Depth : java.util.TreeMap

Tags: java, treemap

How can we set depth of a TreeMap object.
Suppose we are trying to build an auto suggest feature on top of underlying data structure of a TreeMap, how would depth of a tree as we know affect the performance?

Comment: What do you mean by 'depth', exactly?

Comment: usually, depth of a tree means the largest number of nodes from the root to a leaf.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is vague but if I understand correctly, you're misunderstanding concepts. [TreeMap](http://cupi2.uniandes.edu.co/site/images/recursos/javadoc/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is an implementation of the Map interface which uses red-black tree for sorting its contents into natural ascending order while what you're asking is something completely unrelated; ranking items based on their position in a graph.

Answer (score 0):

> How can we set depth of a TreeMap object.

You cannot directly set the (maximum) depth of a TreeMap, or even precisely determine what its depth is.  However, the depth will be *approximately* `ceiling(log2(table.size()))` in the best and worst case.

> Suppose we are trying to build an auto suggest feature on top of underlying data structure of a TreeMap, how would depth of a tree as we know affect the performance?

The average lookup time will be proportional to the average depth of leaf nodes in the tree.

Comment: IIRC, in a red-black tree, the depth can be up to 2*log2(size).