# How do I find the height of a Red-Black Tree using the TreeSet Class in Java?

Tags: java, height, red-black-tree

I currently have a Red-Black created in Java using the java.util.TreeSet Class. I need to be able to find the height of the Red-Black Tree but I am not sure how to with the Java TreeSet class. I have seen some uses of Recursion but I am not sure how to work this with the TreeSet Class.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.Random;

public class BinarySearchTreeTest<E extends Comparable<Integer>>{

static Random randomGenerator = new Random();

public static int randomEven(){
    int randomEven = randomGenerator.nextInt(50000000);

    randomEven = randomEven * 2;

    return randomEven;
}

public static int randomOdd(){
    int randomOdd = randomGenerator.nextInt(49999999);

    randomOdd = randomOdd * 2 + 1;

    return randomOdd;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeSet<Item> RedBlackTree = new TreeSet<Item>();

    int[] randomArray = new int[100000];
    int inserts = 0;
    while(inserts != randomArray.length-1) {
        int randomInt = randomEven();
        boolean found = false;

        for(int j = 0; j < randomArray.length; j++) {
            if (randomInt == randomArray[j]) {
                System.out.println("Duplicate Found: " + randomInt + " at " + inserts);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!found) {
            randomArray[inserts] = randomInt;
            ++inserts;
        }
    }

    //Adds all 100000 values to the Red Black Tree, and stores the number of comparisons
    for (int i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++){
        Item randomItem = new Item(randomArray[i]);
        RedBlackTree.add(randomItem);
    }
    long RedBlackTreeComparison = Item.getCompCount();
    Item.resetCompCount();

    System.out.println("Red Black Tree:");
    //String treeOutput = RedBlackTree.toString();
    //System.out.println(treeOutput);
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.println("Height: N/A " + "     " + "Number of Comparisons: " + RedBlackTreeComparison);
    System.out.println("Contains " + doesContain + " : " + RedBlackTree.contains(doesContain) + "     " + "Number of Comparisons: " + Item.getCompCount());
    System.out.print("\n");
    Item.resetCompCount();

}
```

}

Comment: You're probably not going to succeed at that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690114/set-depth-java-util-treemap

Comment: You cannot know that, it's not part of the interface to provide such info. Also, why do you need it? You may just *calculate* `Math.log(yourTreeSet.size()) / Math.log(2);`

Comment: Part of my uni coursework involves Red-Black Trees and Binary Search Trees. We have been asked to create 1 of each of the Trees, fill them with the same values and then make some graphs based on the Number of Comparisons it takes to find one of the values against the Height of each tree.

Comment: Yeah ... that probably means creating your own implementation of a red-black tree. It so happens that the `TreeSet` is a red-black tree, but I highly doubt this is what your teacher had in mind.

Comment: He actually specifically asked us to use java.util.TreeSet. I will check with him to see what he wants us to do.